# Localhost website redirects to live site in development

Tags: php, apache

Something strange has been happening lately and I'm suspecting some malware has infiltrated my machine or I'm totally oblivious to what is going on. I'm developing a platform on my machine located at `localhost/myproject`. When I type that address it's fine I get directed to `index.php`. However, when I try to get in a sub-directory at `localhost/myproject/user/dashboard.php` I get redirected to some weird live chinese site. Any idea how to fix this? Does it have something to do with the `php.ini`?

Comment: I wouldn't say this would be a php.ini issue. It could be htaccess, it could be DNS hijacking, it could be something in your apache config, or it could be something hiding in your code.

Comment: @aynber: Where can I find the .htaccess? I didn't add one manually. So I'm guessing it has to do with Apache default. And yes, I agree this looks like hijacking but why a sub-directory and not the main one?

Comment: Check your web root directory or any sub directory. Make sure you're looking for hidden files. If you don't have one, then that's probably not the issue.

Comment: @aynber: I just ran the antivirus. I found a trojan and that's about it. Thinking of running Malwarebytes but in case of DNS hijacking, any idea how to get to the root of this problem? I mean all I have to do is revert back to local dns, right?

Comment: Also check your hosts file.

Comment: @aynber: Malwarebytes didn't solve anything. I checked whoismydns.com and f-secure.com and everything's okay with the router. There's no .htaccess in my project right now. I'm confused. What do you mean by the hosts file?

Comment: For *nix/mac os based systems, it's in `/etc/hosts`. For Windows, it may be in `C:\Windows\system32`. You may have to do a search for it.

Comment: @aynber: which file should I look for ?